# how to rewrite this code in netlogo 6.1.1? i think i missed somewhere

Tags: netlogo

I've edited my question
i'm trying to rewrite this line in netlogo 6.1.1 which means ask the current turtle.

NB: s0 is a list of turtle's ID [who] example: s0 [15 14 39 5]

```
to do
 set c0 []                                                                    
  ask turtles with [breed = objets] [set c0 lput who c0]                       
  set d0 []                                                                   
  while [not empty? c0 ][ 
   set s0 []                                                                  
   print s0
   ask turtle one-of c0 [set s0 lput who s0 ] 
   let i 0 let u 1
   while [i != u][                                                            
     set i length s0
     foreach s0 [ask turtle ? [ask neighbors [ask objets-here [set s0 lput who s0 ]]]]  
     set s0 remove-duplicates s0     
     set u length s0 
   ]
end
```

as i undrestood "?" replace the identifier of turtle so i tried this one after consultating The NetLogo dictionary and then i tried as @Luke C told me and i wrote it this way:

```
foreach s0 [ current-turtle -> ask current-turtle [ask neighbors [ask objets-here [set s0 lput who s0 ]]]]
```

but i had a runtime error tha says this time:

> ASK expected input to be an agent or agentset but got the number 242 instead.

can you please explain to me why ?

i think i dident write it the right way can you helpe please? thank you

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you're on the right track. The conversion to 6.XX basically replaces the `?` with a user-defined temporary variable, which allows for easier-reading code. You can therefore just add in the little `your-variable-name ->` at the start of your `foreach` code block and then use that named variable through the remainder of that block. For a very simple example:

```
globals [ s0 ]

to setup 
  ca
  crt 10
  set s0 sort n-of 5 turtles
  reset-ticks
end
  

to go
    foreach s0 [ current-turtle ->
    ask current-turtle [
      fd 2
    ]
  ]
  tick
end
```

**Edit:**

Modified example code for a turtle's `who`:

```
globals [ s0 ]

to setup 
  ca
  crt 40
  set s0 [15 14 39 5]
  reset-ticks
end
  

to go
    foreach s0 [ current-who ->
    ask turtle current-who [
      fd 2
    ]
  ]
  tick
end
```

I should note that generally using the `who` number may not be the best way to go about this, as opposed to simply asking a subset of an agent set,  but the above allows you to use the syntax of `ask turtle NUMBER`.

Comment: well i rewrite the code as your example :   foreach s0 [ current-turtle -> ask current-turtle   [ask neighbors [ask objets-here [set s0 lput who s0 ]]]]                                                       but still have a runtime error tha says his time: ASK  expected input to be an agent or agentset but got the number 242 instead.         can you please explain to me why ?

Comment: @aya_kh - I would guess that it is because your list is not a list of turtles, but a list of turtle `who` values or something similar. However, without knowing more background it's just a guess. If you edit your question to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) I (or someone else) can probably be of more help.

Comment: @aya_kh - Modified the example code to reflect the `who` number use case.